# Instead of using eval() to convert a string to a php math equation?

Tags: php, math, eval, equation

So in the [eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) documentation someone quoted:

> If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong
>   question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

So I don't know how I should ask the question. But what I want is the possibility to:

1. From a form field put an equation with either php variables (`$var['name']`) or some kind of replacement words that turns in to variables later for the equation.
2. Save this equation above to the database.
3. Be able from a php code to run that equation later.

**Note:** There will only be a few administrators for the site that will be able/have permission to create and save these equations to the database.

But anyway, so I shouldn't use `eval()`. What should I use instead? Or how should the question been asked?

Comment: A parser with an interpreter.

Comment: Like e.g. https://packagist.org/packages/mossadal/math-parser - or just enter into google 'php math parser' and you'll find a few packages. With those packages you can then set variables ahead, like setVariables(['name'=>$something]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, it would be best to avoid using `eval` with user input for any reason. For example, if there's bug or vulnerability that allows access to an admin account (minor things, like XSS, etc), they can now execute code on your server.

As mentioned above, a better choice would be using a math parser.

I've had good experience with [hoa/math](https://github.com/hoaproject/Math), which support variables, custom functions, constants and more.

Comment: I'm not using Vendor. Is it possible to just download the package with everything needed?